# Is it possible to create an ASP.NET user with 2 separate passwords?

Tags: c#, asp.net, passwords, asp.net-identity

By dafault ASP.NET identity user has, among others, a password hash column

```
PasswordHash (nvarchar(max), null)
```

And using ASP.NET identities default methods like

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(Tkey userId, string currentPassword, string newPassword);
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> RemovePasswordAsync(Tkey userId);
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(Tkey userId, string token, string newPassword);
```

Makes it easy to change, reset or update the password.

If I wanted to add another password to the user, something like

```
Password2Hash (nvarchar(max), null)
```

Is there a way to use the same methods to manipulate the second password too?

How much of the default ASP.NET identity methods would I need to override to achieve this?

The passwords would have the same validation rules but other than that would be completely independent of each other.

Comment: This is a really weird requirement, something I've never seen before, why would you want two passwords for a user? I'm betting this is somewhat of an XY problem and there are better ways to achieve what you are looking to do.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: It's something similar to a two factor authentication. User needs to enter the first password to log into the system and performing certain actions will required the user to enter the second password.

Comment: I'm curious how you think this will be any better than a single password?

Comment: Basically if you know someone's password this would stop you from accessing part of the system. It's mostly effective against phishing scams and similar instance where a user would give away his password. Not completely safe but it's a little less likely that the user will give away both of his passwords.

Comment: Except it doesn't really do that. If someone gives away one password, they're just as likely to give away both, human nature sadly. If this worked, it would be used everywhere. Why can't you just set up 2FA?

Comment: I already have 2FA with first password, this is just an extra layer of protection. About it not being used, where I'm from it's a common security measure, I would say even more widely used than 2FA. I kind of assumed it's the same everywhere but I guess it could just be a local thing.